# Does fitnesse have ability to run one test several times with different parameters

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I want to run the same test with different parameters, like @Parameterized.Parameters in junit. Does fitnesse have ability to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely--that is probably *the* fundamental capability of FitNesse. Consider the basic test table in FitNesse:

```
!|Evaluate Inputs          |
|Param1|Param2|Calculation?|
|0     |1     |1           |
```

- The first row identifies the method under test--in this case `EvaluateInputs`.
- The second row names the inputs and outputs. Outputs are distinguished by the presence of a question mark (?) suffix. Thus, this method has two inputs (`Param1` and `Param2`) and one output (`Calculation`).
- The third row specifies the inputs to the test and the expected outcome: in pseudo-code this case yields `EvaluateInputs( 0, 1 ) => 1`.

To test other combinations of valid inputs for this method, just add additional rows to the test table:

```
!|Evaluate Inputs          |
|Param1|Param2|Calculation?|
|0     |1     |1           |
|1     |0     |1           |
|0     |0     |0           |
|1     |1     |0           |
```

(For more examples, see the first section of [part 6 of my series](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/acceptance-testing-with-fitnesse-multiplicities-and-comparisons/)  of articles **Acceptance Testing with FitNesse** published on Simple-Talk.com.)

Answer (score 1):

I know this , however I don't how to use it in my case.I want to run my tests three times using different  "NetworkManager" each time, which is created in "Create NetworkManager with connector type JSON"

```
!define groupAdminName {ALEX_ADMIN}

!|Script|com.playtech.openapi.core.fitnesse.tests.NetworkManagerSetUp|
|Create NetworkManager with connector type JSON                      |
|Create NetworkManager with connector type PROTOBUF                  |
|Create NetworkManager with connector type PROTOSTUFF                |


!2 1)Create member which will be admin of the group
!| Script|com.playtech.openapi.core.fitnesse.tests.Fixtures|
|Create context                                            |
|Create member with name ${groupAdminName}
```

Comment: Hi, Wood! Did you find solution for your case? I tried to find/implement something you described.